# Image path says cannot read even with permissions given (Android Studio) java

Tags: java, android, permissions

I am new to Android and I am trying to get the Uri of an image that a user selects from the downloads folder. Currently, I am able to open the downloads folder and select an image. However, when I take the path of the image selected, file.canRead() returns false.

These are the permissions that I have provided for the app

```
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int permission2 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permission2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }
```

Here is where I am  taking the image that I selected from the download folder and then passed the path to a new file:

```
        selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
        String path = getRealPathFromURI(getApplicationContext(), selectedImage);
        File selPath = new File(path);


        Boolean b5 = selPath.isFile();
        Boolean b1 = selPath.canRead();
        Boolean b2 = selPath.exists();
```

isFile() returns true

exists() returns true

canRead() returns false, and I don't know why because I have given permissions.

Comment: `getRealPathFromURI()` is guaranteed to be wrong. Delete it. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in the content identified by the `Uri` (`selectedImage` in your code snippet).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the quick reply.  Initially I was not using the getRealPathFromURI and I was still getting False for isFile().  Hence, I tried getting the real path to see if it helps.  It didn't.  I need to pass the selected file to another method where I want to compare it to another image.  I am having trouble with accessing the files itself..

Comment: "I was still getting False for isFile()" -- stop thinking in terms of files. You are not working with files. You are working with content identified by a `Uri`. I do not know exactly how you plan to compare this image with another image, but `BitmapFactory` can read in a `Bitmap` from an `InputStream`. You can get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri` using a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`.